# oracle home user

Tags: oracle, windows-10, delete-file

I have windows 10 64 bit

I try to re install oracle database 12c

i delete all files .. from directories .. from services. from regedit .. from temp.. from c disk .. from everywhere i remove oracle files all also i run ccleaner but when i try to install oracle database12c again

then in this step this show oraclehomeuser1 already exist :O

[image]

i dont why where it is located

any solution please

Comment: During instalation you're choosing built-in account or creating new user for Oracle?

Comment: i choose create new windows user @Kacper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that as part of the Oracle 12c installation process, you created an 'Oracle Home User' account.  This user account is used to run all database services.  You haven't done anything wrong here: I've created Oracle Home Users for Oracle 12c databases I've set up.

Evidently as part of your uninstallation you didn't remove this user account.

Remove this user account, using [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/559514/) if the user doesn't appear in Control Panel, and try again.

Comment: how i remove this user account and where .. as i mentioned i remove all oracle files/folders/names etc..

Comment: @greenuser: from Control Panel, or the Settings app.

Comment: in control panel there is only 1 user with my name .. not oraclehomeuser

Comment: check this control panel image .. http://i.imgur.com/hcSQkbu.png @Kacper

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/559514/how-do-i-remove-a-user-account-which-is-invisible-on-the-logon-screen-or-user-ma maybe this will help @greenuser

Comment: @Kacper: thanks for that link, I wasn't aware it would be so difficult to get rid of that user account.

Comment: press WIN+R , Type lusrmgr.msc, press enter, double click users in left pane, delete the Oracle home user you create during instalatiom

Answer (score 1):

press WIN+R , Type lusrmgr.msc, press enter, double click users in left pane, delete the Oracle home user you create during instalatiom –
Tayyab Mazhar

Thanks Tayyab.. this is perfect answer.